# Is this true that, any algebraic curve has finitely many singularities?

Tags: calculus, algebraic-geometry, differential-geometry, algebraic-curves

Can we say that any algebraic curve has finitely many singularities?

Comment: What is your definition of an algebraic curve?

Comment: If you take the curve $y^2=0$ in the $xy$-plane (or the projective plane), then every point is a singular point. So you probably want to require that the curve be *reduced*.

Comment: for a reduced curve, pages 92-93, of Shafarevich's BAG vol 1, argue that the set of singular points is a closed proper subset, hence finite.  this argument depends however on a false corollary on p. 77 about upper semi continuity of dimension of fibers of a map.  the corollary is true for proper maps, so modify the argument by projectivizing the tangent bundle of the variety to fix it.

Comment: I think the argument in Chapter I.5 of Hartshorne is good. The singular locus is defined by the vanishing of certain determinants of partial derivatives, so it's closed; you just need to show that it's a proper subset (I hope the finiteness is then clear, when the variety has dimension $1$). That's a little bit trickier, but Hartshorne has an argument.

Comment: @roysmith - I have two questions: a) What is difference between  reduced curve shape and non reduced curve? b) Let we have closed proper subset. Why does finite? thank you.

Comment: @Hoot -  I have two questions: a) What is difference between reduced curve shape and non reduced curve? b) Let we have closed proper subset. Why does finite? thank you

Comment: you need to read the definition of  curve somewhere.  if the definition is just a set of points, the curve is reduced.  if the definition also invoves  choice of ring of regular functions, then the structure and the reducedness, depend on that ring, i.e. on the equations chosen to define the set.  in Ted's example above, the x axis can be defined by the equation y=0, which makes it reduced, and also by the equation y^2=0, which makes it non reduced.  a proper closed subset has lower dimension, so on a curve has dimension zero.  Then the finiteness inherent in algebraic subsets makes it finite.

Comment: briefly, the ring of regular functions is the polynomial ring modulo the equation, so in the examples just given for x axis, either k[X,Y]/(Y) or k[X,Y]/(Y^2).  Then reducedness is the property that this ring has no non zero nilpotents, true of the first (since there Y is zero), not the second, where Y is nilpotent, but not zero, i.e. there Y^2 is zero, not Y.

Comment: basically, the singularities are defined by the equation of the curve and its partial derivatives.  moreover the set of common solutions of any two distinct irreducible equations in the plane is finite as shown early in this free, highly recommended book on curves.  http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~wfulton/CurveBook.pdf

Comment: I guess we still need to say why a dimension zero algebraic set is finite. I think this should just follow from the finiteness of the number of irreducible components.