# Projective curve without regular points?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, finite-fields, algebraic-curves

Let $C$ be some integral projective curve on some field $k$. Can $C$ consist only singular points (except the generic point)?  From [Is this true that, any algebraic curve has finitely many singularities?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1819769/is-this-true-that-any-algebraic-curve-has-finitely-many-singularities) I see that $C$ can contain only finitely many singular points. Hence if $C$ consists only singular ponints (except the generic point, which is always regular under the integral assumption), then it has only finitely many points.

Then $k$ should be a finite field (I dont know how to show this, but I think it should be true). And then is such a $C$?

Just wanna to find an (counter)example while studying projective curves. Any algebraic curves with only singular points, or different assumptions are OK too. Thank you in advanced!

Comment: It may depend on what a curve is for you. If you work with schemes (are you working with schemes?) the answer is no - all integral curves have an open subset which is smooth.

Comment: Note that regularity and smoothness of $C$ will only coincide if $k$ is perfect, so you should specify which you mean. If $C$ is the product over $k$ of a smooth geometrically integral $k$-curve $C'$ and the spectrum of a finite purely inseparable extension of $k$, then $C$ is nowhere smooth. However, if $k$ is perfect (eg if $k$ is finite), then the regular locus is open and so $C$ cannot consist only of singular points (see https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/07R2).

Comment: Yeah I do work on scheme. I see the result now (In Vakil’s FOAG): “21.6.1. Theorem (generic smoothness of varieties). — If X is an irreducible finite type k-scheme over a perfect field k of dimension n, there is a dense open subset U of X such that U is smooth (over k) of dimension n.” For an integral curve I mean “dimensional 1 irreducible k-variety” over some field $k$. @KReiser

Comment: Yeah. Being confused on the subtlety between regularity and smoothness I haven’t organized the question in a good way. The example and the link to SP should be what exactly I want to know. @DamianRössler

Comment: You are conflating two different meanings of the word "point." Since you mention the generic point it sounds like you mean points in the scheme sense. But then you talk about finite fields, where it sounds like you mean $k$-points. These are quite different; which do you mean? Note that if you're talking about $k$-points and $k$ is not algebraically closed then it's possible for a curve to have no $k$-points at all, in which case it is vacuously true that they're all singular.

Comment: I am considering all points on an algebraic curves(i.e., purely dimensional 1 $k$-variety, or more precisely, purely dimensional 1 $k$-scheme which is finite type, seperated, and reduced), on which all points except the generic points of each irreducible components are closed due to dimension reason. I see now for $k$-points some more examples like $\operatorname{Spec}\Bbb{R}[x,y]/(x^2+y^2)$ which has exactly 1 $\Bbb{R}$-points and moreover it's singular. Since I am seeking some examples to solid my understanding, all these are nice. Thank you for poniting the mix up out. @QiaochuYuan

Comment: If you're considering points in the scheme sense then every curve has infinitely many points, even over a finite field.

Comment: Yeah I found it from here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2892962/finitely-generated-k-algebra-of-krull-dimension-one-has-infinitely-many-primes